# Angular js scope variable (array) changes not reflected in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, ejs

I am binding a scope variable, an array to ng-repeat div tag (a table basically).
When I dynamically add any data to the array, it works! A row is added to the table.

But when I remove an element from the array, the change doesn't reflect on the table. One row should be removed.

Following is the code that I'm working with (Javascript):

```
    $scope.myfields = [];
    $scope.addField = function () {
        $scope.myfields.push({ "name": "", "type": "", "required": "", "enum": "" });
        console.log("add: " + $scope.myfields.length);
        console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.myfields));
    }

    $scope.removeField = function (index) {
        $scope.myfields.splice(index, 1);
        console.log("remove: " + $scope.myfields.length);
        console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.myfields));
    }
```

EJS: Please see below!

Weird thing is,
In console log, it says that changes are made as expected to $scope variable, only view(table) is not getting updated.
And if I don't put "track by $index", add and remove both stops reflecting in table!

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT 2:
The code you have asked for:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                    <p style="text-align:center"><strong>DEFINE CUSTOM FIELDS:</strong></p>
                    <br>
                    <div style="text-align:center">
                        Click on '+' button to add custom field:
                        <div class="fa fa-plus-circle" ng-click='addField()'> </div>
                        <div class="fa fa-minus-circle" ng-click='removeField(0)'> </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div  data-responsive-table>
                        <table  data-table>
                            <thead >
                            <tr >
                                <th  data-event='sort'>
                                Field Name
                                </th>
                                <th  data-event='sort'>
                                Type
                                </th>
                                <th data-event='sort'>
                                Is Required?
                                </th>
                                <th  data-event='sort'>
                                Enumeration
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody >
                            <tr  data-parent-row ng-repeat="um in dynamicFields track by $index">
                                <td>
                                    <input placeholder="Name" ng-model="um.name" validation="required" >
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select style='height: 45px;'   ng-model="um.type" >
                                        <option value="string">string</option>
                                        <option value="boolean">boolean</option>
                                        <option value="integer">integer</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select style='height: 45px;'   ng-model="um.required" >
                                        <option  value="true">true</option>
                                        <option value="false">false</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input placeholder="Enum" ng-model="um.enum" validation="required" >
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: post the code where you invoke removeField() and addField() and where you define dynamicFields array

Comment: How do you trigger your removeField function, via ng-click ?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Show the code where your calling removeField.

Comment: Please check the edit! Thanks for your inputs..

Comment: you are always removing 0 index , I think this may be the issue

Comment: @AbhisekMalakar hey, it is purposely done! but still the table that is rendered is not changed.. It should have removed the first row of the table. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I have tried a snippet with this and it's working for me, You can use <span class="debug">{{myfields | json}}</span> tag in the template, and move this tag in the template to check at which point it get detached from the scope, and just a guess that due the directive "data-parent-row" may cause any glitch?

Comment: @AbhisekMalakar Hey, its still not working for me.. I have tried after removing data-parent-row tag.. still no use.. and I have tested this across browsers, and across different machines.. I am surprised to know it worked in your machine! In mine, new rows are added on (+) but remove (-) doesn't work! Please help..

Comment: the span code display the myfields array in string representation, and by using that you can check that in template what is actually reflecting .First try to place the span tag just below the remove button. If the value is Ok, there then dig the dom and place the span in inner dom structure gradually

Answer (score 1):

The variable name in your ng-repeat should be `myfields` and not `dynamicfields`

Since in your controller it is `$scope.myfields`, in your view it should be

```
ng-repeat="um in myfields track by $index"
```

Comment: It was a mistake in editing question, the names are same in the code